# Как написать триггер который будет считать количество записей в одной таблице и результат переносить в другую таблицу по id?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, триггер

С помощью этих таблиц у меня не выходит реализовать такой триггер, чтобы при добавлении записи в таблицу "tasks", триггер бы подсчитывал количество записей в таблице "tasks"  и отправлял бы результат в таблицу "modules." в поле "num_of_task"

Пример исполнения триггра:
Когда добавил 2-е записи в "tasks" триггер подсчитывает количество записей и отправляет результат подсчёта в "num_of_task" таблицы "modules" с учетом того что к примеру одна запись относится к первуму модулю, а вторая ко второму модулю, то есть чтобы было распределение задач по модулю, распределение по id индитификатору
Заранее очень благодарен за помощь!
Таблица задания:

[image]

Таблица модули:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества, изменил текст объяснение, надесь в этот раз смогу донести то что необходимо

Comment: Переопределённые данные - зло. Нафига считать триггером? когда понадобится количество - посчитаете в запросе по таблице `tasks`.

Comment: @Akina, тогда я не смогу увидеть модуль, в котором будет указана такая информация: "Количество заданий в модуле: 4", а модулей много и к каждому модулю принадлежит своя задача, вот эти задачи я и хочу распределить по модулям

Comment: Это ещё почему? таблицы связаны? связаны... посчитаете количество не вообще, а группируя по модулю, и потом, если надо, привяжете информацию из таблицы модулей.

Comment: @Akina, я попробовал, но запрос у меня считает только у одного модуля и присваевает ему количесвтво всех задач, а не те, которые принадлежат ему.  Понимаю что что-то не так, но не понимаю где именно SELECT modules.id,COUNT(tasks.id_module) FROM tasks INNER JOIN modules ON tasks.id_module=modules.id WHERE tasks.id_module=modules.id;

Comment: А не почитать ли Вам про GROUP BY? А заодно - про ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Comment: @Akina, большое спасибо всего лишь нужно было дополнить это GROUP BY modules.id;